# Change row in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I would like to change the `key` value and also tried to create a test in SQLfiddle, but it did not work. The below output I have got from pgAdmin3:

```
Select * from api_keys;

id, create_time, user_id, key
1;"2015-11-17 01:23:08.872941";1;"d0dff17e3753a88d298ae775bb32eee6"
```

How is it possible to change the `key` value in `api_keys`?

Comment: It does not sound clear;  what are you trying to achieve? for psql updates - read - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-update.html

Answer (score 0):

You mean [`UPDATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html)?

To change all rows with `key = 'd0dff17e3753a88d298ae775bb32eee6'`:

```
UPDATE api_keys
SET    key = 'd0dff17e3753a88d298ae775bb32eee7'
WHERE  key = 'd0dff17e3753a88d298ae775bb32eee6';
```